# PHP - какой самый быстрый способ поиска значения одного массива в другом?

Tags: php

Есть два одномерных массива. Каждый примерно по 1млн. ключей-значений.

```php
$array1 = [
    'test_string1',
    'test_string2',
];

$array2 = [
    'test_string1_fromfile1',
    'test_string9993_2021_10',
];
```

Нужно проверить, что в `$array2` есть элемент, который содержит подстроку из `$array1`? Мы должны по **test_string1** из `$array1` пройти по всему `$array2` до первого совпадения значения (**test_string1**_fromfile1), потом можно сделать `break` и перейти к следующему значению из `$array1`. Можно через `preg_grep()`, но насколько я понимаю он выбирает все совпадающие значения, а нам не обязательно идти по всему массиву, если мы уже нашли совпадение. Задача сделать это максимально быстро на PHP.

Comment: Можете попробовать склеить второй массив в гигантскую строку и искать в ней функциями поиска в строке. Быстродействие не гарантирую.

Comment: @ArchDemon Да и корректность тоже не гарантируете.

Comment: @user7860670, ну не бездумно же склеивать. Через разделитель, которого гарантированно нет в исходных строках

Comment: @ArchDemon А то. Затем последует вопрос, как максимально быстро найти такой разделитель на php.

Answer (score -1):

Не претендую на правоту, но вот такой кейс:

```php
<?php

// https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1357313/201026

echo "----------------------------------------\n";
echo phpversion() . "\n";
echo "----------------------------------------\n";

// ----------------------------------------

$array1 = ['99999', '100000'];

$array2 = range(0, 1e5);

foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    foreach ($array2 as $item2) {
        if (strpos($item2, $item1) !== false) {
            $endTime = microtime(true);
            echo
                'Item 1: ' . $item1 . "\n",
                'Item 2: ' . $item2 . "\n",
                'Time: ' . ($endTime - $startTime);
            echo "\n----------------------------------------\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

$array2AsString = implode($array2);

foreach ($array1 as $item1) {
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    if (strpos($array2AsString, $item1) !== false) {
        $endTime = microtime(true);
        echo
            'Item 1: ' . $item1 . "\n",
            'Time: ' . ($endTime - $startTime);
        echo "\n----------------------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Один из результатов:

```
----------------------------------------
8.0.8
----------------------------------------
Item 1: 99999
Item 2: 99999
Time: 0.056140899658203
----------------------------------------
Item 1: 100000
Item 2: 100000
Time: 0.065861940383911
----------------------------------------
Item 1: 99999
Time: 0.00022983551025391
----------------------------------------
Item 1: 100000
Time: 0.00037479400634766
----------------------------------------
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/StableOrderlyLifecycle#main.php

Comment: Хотя SO не поддерживает воспроизведение мультимедиа, но в этом ответе явственно слышится [характерная мелодия](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8OJB5qLZ6o). Особенно доставляет повышенная продуктивность предлагаемого решения, позволяющая находить даже те элементы, которых нет (например в случае `$array1 = ['99']; $array2 = ['19','91'];`),  и элегантное решение с выносом конструкции `$array2AsString = implode($array2);` вне измерения затраченного времени.

Comment: Я бы в implode добавил разделитель, которого гарантированно нет в искомых строках. Так мы избежим ошибок, которые описаны в комментарии выше

Comment: Можно ли поделить массив на части в котором ищем и искать в частях параллельно?